Как отсортировать текст в файле по первой колонке?
есть файл hello.txt c содержанием
1,3,5
4,1,2,3
3,2,4
2,3,1

как отсортировать строки в файле по первому столбцу?
и получить файл hellosort.txt
1,3,5
2,3,1
3,2,4
4,1,2,3

c содержанием
подскажите пример кода на bash

А вы знаете, что языки программирования бывают разные?

@MBo,    точно? ..............

Ээм, а что, sort уже запретили?

Ну да, в линуксе же есть sort готовый, в чём вопрос то и при чём здесь питон?

Читайте доки, будет примерно так:
sort -t, -o hellosort.txt hello.txt

